# Merge IPRanges into one range

Tags: c#, ip-address

I have the following small class:

```
public class IPRange
{
    public IPAddress From { get; set; }
    public IPAddress To { get; set; }

    public IPRange(IPAddress from, IPAddress to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }
}
```

How can I check if two IPRanges are overlapping each other, and if so, merge both ipranges into one new IPRange? The solution must be both IPv4 and IPv6 compliant.

Are there methods to compare two ipaddress objects? I cannot immediately find them.
For example 10.12.0.2 > 10.12.0.1 should be true

Comment: for ipv4 get their int32_t representation and just compare

Comment: what about ipv6 which is 128bit?

Comment: Do you want to merge only overlapping ranges or also adjacent ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check two addresses of any type (but the same type), for example IPv6 addresses, by comparing bytes:

```
IPAddress addr1 = IPAddress.Parse("2001:db8::1:2");
IPAddress addr2 = IPAddress.Parse("2001:db8::1:1");
var bytes1 = addr1.GetAddressBytes();
var bytes2 = addr2.GetAddressBytes();
Console.WriteLine(CompareBytes(bytes1, bytes2) > 0);  // Prints: "True"
```

And the `CompareBytes` method:

```
private static int CompareBytes(byte[] left, byte[] right)
{
    // TODO: Null checks.
    // TODO: Check that left and right have the same length.

    int difference = 0;
    for (int i = left.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        difference = left[i] - right[i];
        if (difference != 0)
            break;
    }
    return difference;
}
```

This works regardless of the *endianness* of the system your code is running on.

---

You can convert any IPv4 address to an equivalent IPv6 address like this:

```
var ipv6 = ipv4.MapToIPv6();
```

---

If you are sure you always have IPv4 addresses, you can compare just their integer values:

```
IPAddress addr1 = IPAddress.Parse("10.12.0.2");
IPAddress addr2 = IPAddress.Parse("10.12.0.1");
uint value1 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(addr1.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
uint value2 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(addr2.GetAddressBytes(), 0);
Console.WriteLine(value1 > value2);   // Prints: "True"
```

Comment: You can compare IPv4 with IPv6 with bytes, but you have to ensure that the IPv4 bytes are filled with 0 at the start of the array

Comment: @DariuszWawer [Apparently](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.maptoipv6.aspx) IPv4 addresses converted to IPv6 must be prefixed with `0:0:0:0:0:FFFF`.